# Android custom scheme deep link does not work on click

Tags: android, deep-linking

i searched a lot and i read many answers but unfortunately i didn't manage to make it work.

I am testing deep link on my app and i can not make custom scheme url work on click.

My Manifest code is :

```
   <activity android:name=".ui.activities.home.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <!-- for http links -->
        <intent-filter android:label="testHttpDeepLink">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.myapp.com/test” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.myapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/test" />
        </intent-filter>
            <!-- for app links -->
        <intent-filter
            android:label="testAppDeepLink">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp" -->
            <data android:scheme="myapp"
                android:host="*"/>
    </activity>
```

When i am trying to test it on studio terminal the second format works fine. So if i write

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://test"
```

app home activity opens correct. But when i try to open it from a link it does not work. For example i send an email to myself with possible formats, for example

```
1 -> www.myapp.com/test
2 -> myapp://test
```

The first works fine but the second not. It shows message error: `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` when i click to the url. Only if i press long click and select open then drives me to app home activity.

Comment: (I removed the scheme tag since it is not related to the Scheme programming language, apparently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is not a valid value for a `android:host`.
Simply remove it and it will work.

Also, this method is heavily reliant on the app handling the url in the first place.
If your browser doesn't let the system handle non-http scheme, you won't be able to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I remove * without have any effect. Probably is the last you said that my browser does not let the system handle non-http scheme.